# material-ui tabs with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a project in material-ui, nextjs and typescript.  I'm trying to get my navbar to work with nextjs:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Link from "next/link";
import {Tab, Tabs} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs>
              <Tab label="Timer"><Link href="timer" /> </Tab>
              <Tab label="Home" to="/" component={Link}  />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
  );
}
```

But it causes the build to fail.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what is the error-message if the build failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I believe you want to wrap the `<Tab />` elements with the `<Link />` ones.

```
<Tabs>
    <Link href="/timer" passHref>
      <Tab label="Timer" />
    </Link>
    <Link href="/" passHref>
      <Tab label="Home" />
    </Link>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: variant="fullWidth" and evenly spacing the tabs does not seem to work with this solution, did you at all find a solution for this also?

Answer (score 3):

Other solutions basically wrap the Next.js' `Link` around MUI's `Tab`. It probably breaks the compatibility between `Tabs` and `Tab`.

Why not style `Link` to fill the entire `Tab`? Code for MUI v5:

```
<Tab
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
  }}
  label={
    <Link href={opt['href']} passHref>
      <Typography
        component="a"
        sx={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0
        }}
      >
        {opt['label']}
      </Typography>
    </Link>
  }
  value={opt['value']}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
...

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  ...
  <Tabs value={selected} onChange={(_e, v) => setSelected(v)} ...>
    <Tab
      component={Link}
      href="/timer"
      label="Timer"
    />
    <Tab
      component={Link}
      href="/"
      label="Home"
    />
  </Tabs>
```

This also works with `variant="fullWidth"`.

Comment: Great solution that keeps default Tab styling.

Answer (score 2):

This might be better for SEO:

```
<Link href="/timer" passHref>
  <Tab component="a" label="Timer" />
</Link>
```

Reason is because `Link` doesn't add `href` to the child (even if it's an `a` component). `passHref` forces this, but `preventDefault` can't be put `onClick` as mentioned in the [MUI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#nav-tabs) as it won't change the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Keep all MUI styles

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import {Tab} from "@mui/material";
import {forwardRef} from "react";

const LinkTab = forwardRef(({href, ...rest}, ref) => (
  <Link href={href} passHref ref={ref}>
    <Tab component="a" {...rest}/>
  </Link>
))

export default LinkTab
```

Comment: Are you using Next.js 13?

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example straight from MUI v.5.

https://codesandbox.io/s/d2dco?file=/demo.tsx

Create LinkTab component:

```
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';

interface LinkTabProps {
  label?: string;
  href?: string;
}

function LinkTab(props: LinkTabProps) {
  return (
    <Tab
      component="a"
      onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
   <LinkTab label="register" href="/register" />
   <LinkTab label="login" href="/login" />
```

But to be honest `<Tab label="login" href="/login" />` just works for me

Comment: That doesn't address OP's issue of using Material UI's `<Tab>` with Next.js' `<Link>` component, though.

Comment: @juliomalves OP's issue was the 'not working navigation'. My example makes the navigation work with Next.js, without the `<Link>` component.

Comment: Sure, but there's a reason why `next/link` is used, it allows for proper client-side navigation without full page reloads.

Comment: Im not sure if it was just implied but I had to use the router hook to navigate to use this solution. The accepted solution did not work with variant='fullWidth'