# How can I create an AppBar with Tabs as Link component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I would like to use Material-UI's `Tabs` and `Tab` components in my `AppBar` using Next.js and its `Link` component.

Very schematically, this is what I tried:

```
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

  const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setSelectedTab(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Tabs value={selectedTab} onChange={handleTabChange} indicatorColor="secondary">
        <Tab label="Album" />
        <Tab label="Profile" />
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
  )
}
```

The indicator (underlining) and active class works that way, but I'm struggling to use Next.js `Link` component while keeping those functioning.

I tried wrapping the `Tab` components with `Link` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471275/material-ui-tabs-with-nextjs), like this:

```
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

  const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setSelectedTab(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Tabs value={selectedTab} onChange={handleTabChange} indicatorColor="secondary">
        <Link href="/album" passHref>
          <Tab label="Album" />
        </Link>
        <Link href="/profile" passHref>
          <Tab label="Profile" />
        </Link>
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
  )
}
```

This works to redirect me but the indicator and the active class both stop working.

How can I use both the `Link` component from next.js while keeping all the active highlighting functionality of the `Tabs` component from MUI?